# Session amongst Angular and rest services on rails and java

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, angularjs

How would you do session management for a website develloped in angular that consumes two types of REST services. The first is developped in ruby and the other is developped in Java Spring. For now I manage it with a shared table in a mysql database and a session id but i don't think this is the best solution.

A example of this problem is: how does the tomcat server knows about the session used by the rails application?

Thank you,
Davy

Comment: i think you did not get the concept of sessions. it should not matter where you get your data from.

Comment: if you consume webservices you should not see how it's implemented. furthermore: it should not matter.

Comment: Thank you Philipp, a rest client should be stateless indeed but the server has also to keep track of sessions not only the client, how do you manage that across application servers.

Comment: the REST server should not keep track of sessions. he only gets requests and responds to them. The client–server communication is constrained by no client context being stored on the server between requests.

Comment: Does that mean that you would trust on the jsesssionid parameter and send it across different services or a kind of oauth keys?

Comment: And would this work on a cluster of tomcats (new for me)

Comment: if you need some kind of authentication, use basic-authentication or some kind of security framework

Comment: you can store sessions... but that's not really "REST like"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST servers should not do any session management.

they only get requests and responds to them. The client–server communication is constrained by no client context being stored on the server between requests.

How you are doing your session management in your application should not be affected by what resource provider you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Philipp that a REST service should be as stateless as possible however I need some state in my appliation. (authentication)

I have found an article that gives the solution for my problem in this post about
[session stickiness](https://serverfault.com/questions/32421/how-is-session-stickiness-achieved-across-multiple-web-servers). This comes close to my situation of application servers on different machines and with different technologies.

In short they give 3 solutions:

1. maintain a session through cookies en session ids
2. use a database or cache
3. don't use a round robin technique but always let the load balancer send your request to the machine that stores your session. (not when you use diffent technologies)I.